# Dynamically populating <li> within jQuery Mobile data-role=listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

While using jQuery Mobile `<ul data-role="listview">`, I am trying to add some `<li>`s from JavaScript, but the new `<li>` is not inheriting the jQuery Mobile styles. Here is the code:

```
<head>
  <script>
    function init()
    {
      msg = "<li> <a href=> New List Item </a></li>";
      document.querySelector('#add_item').innerHTML +=  msg;
    }

    // call init on load
    window.addEventListener('load',init,false);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='main' data-role='page' data-theme='c'>
    <div data-role='header'>
      <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    </div>
    <div id='content' data-role='content'>
      <ul data-role="listview" id="list_cars">
        <div id="add_item">
        </div>

        <li> <a href=""> List Item 1</a></li>
        <li> <a href=""> List Item 1</a></li>      
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role='footer'>
      <h4>Enjoy reading the book ...</h4>
    </div>
  </div>  <!-- End of Min page -->
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? I'm not sure what the problem is (what's "JSQUERY styles")?

Answer (score 5):

First, you're putting your `<li>` inside a `<div>` instead of directly inside the `<ul>`. Try changing your querySelector to...

```
document.querySelector('#list_cars').innerHTML +=  msg;
```

or, if you want the item at the top of the list, use this...

```
document.querySelector('#list_cars').innerHTML = msg + document.querySelector('#list_cars').innerHTML;
```

Then, you need to tell jQuery Mobile to update that list view by adding...

```
$('#list_cars').listview('refresh');
```

The last section on this [jQuery Mobile Documentation page about lists](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html) describes this feature.

Working example here: http://jsbin.com/omepob/1/

Comment: This is adding the list but it is not coming as the jQuery like view.

Comment: Hi Travis, the problem is that when i am adding the li code from JS, it is not inheriting the jQuery styles. check the code here, you will get it : http://jsbin.com/uvesil/4/

Comment: @user2041129, I see the issue now. I edited my answer. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 2):

To apply the properties on the new object, the optimal way is to call jQuery's refresh method for the object:

```
$("#myobject").listview("refresh");
```

However, I encourage you to replace this innerHTML call for something more DOM-atic, like:

```
var myli = document.createElement("li");
myli.appendChild(document.createTextElement("List Item 3"));
```

BTW, agreed with Travis; better include a "ul" as a parent of "li" instead of using a "div" there...